# API Post request authorization 401 in jquery

Tags: jquery, api, post, http-status-code-401

I think I have searched through the entire web for an answer and I'm still stuck. I try to console log a response from cinesa.es POST api but I can't get through the authorization problem.

I tried in postman and get an answer with the key I got from them placed in the body, but on the web I only get a 401 response with false.

The error code before response in console: POST https://www.cinesa.es/ApiFilms **net::ERR_ABORTED 401**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var request = new Request('https://www.cinesa.es/ApiFilms', {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'cors', 
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: new Headers({
        'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/json',
        'Authorization': 'XXXXXXX'
    })
});

// Now use it!
fetch(request).then(function(response) { 
    console.log(response); /* handle response */ 
});
```

Any adwise how to move forward from this?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a `.catch()` in `fetch()`?

Comment: fetch function takes a url. Which library are you using for fetch function?

Comment: Library? Sorry you lost me! The url is: www.cinesa.es/ApiFilms/

Answer (score 0):

According to http header authorization [official doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) you must specify authorization[space]secret key. Have u tried to do so?

So in your particaular case it has to be:

`{Authorization: Basic XXXXXX}`

Comment: Yes, I've tried to put the authorization as written in both header and body but still the same error message.